# Pulling and Resolving PR conflicts from AzDO

Tags: git, github, azure-devops

My company uses Azure DevOps for source control.  For the most part it works just like GitHub, but I can't figure out how to do this one scenario.  Another co-worker has raised a PR but there are conflicts in his PR.  How can I pull down the PR and resolve the conflicts locally.  Yes, he should do that, but he's going to be out for awhile.  I want to be able to see the conflict markers locally and resolve them in VSCode.
I've tried this command locally:  *git fetch origin pull/27561/head:fixpr*
but that just returns: *fatal: couldn't find remote ref pull/27561/head*

Comment: You've stumbled across the reason that "pull request" is specific to the web hosting site. :-) I don't know the answer to your question, but I do know how you can find out whether there is an answer: use `git ls-remote`. If the name of the remote hosting the AzDO repo is `origin`, `git ls-remote origin` will spill out all the refs your Git can see on AzDO. Eyeballing these, you may be able to figure out which one(s) go(es) with the PR.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no such method could pull down the PR to your local machine directly.

If you want to resolve the conflicts on your local machine, you need to clone the repo, then do a git pull locally to find out the conflicting files.

Finally you can change the file and push to Azure Repo.

Refer to this official doc to get the detailed steps: [Resolve merge conflicts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/merging?view=azure-devops&tabs=command-line)

On the other hand, you can also consider using this extension: [Pull Request Merge Conflict Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.conflicts-tab) to resolve conflicts directly in Azure DevOps Pull Requests.

You can see the **Conflicts** tab in the Pull Request.

For example:

[image]